# Object is not released after dealloc

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory

Heapshots show that objects are not released, and at the same time logs show that dealloc was called. i do release all properties and remove all superviews in dealloc. So why memory is still not released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dealloc` was called, but the memory backing the object was not released, there are two possibilities:

1. You did not call `[super dealloc]` at the end of your `-dealloc` (only applies to non-ARC code)
2. You have Zombies enabled. This can be done either via a checkbox in Instruments (in the configuration for the ObjectAlloc instrument), or via the Diagnostics tab in the Scheme editor.

Comment: Yes, i call [super dealloc], and i have just checked Zombies - they are disabled everywhere.

Comment: @flybirdx: What makes you think the object isn't being released? Are you sure you have Instruments configured to only show live objects?

Comment: yes, they are configured to track only active allocations, and memory monitor shows memory consumption growth. And, finally - after like 150 iteration it crashes after memory warning.

Comment: @flybirdx: What's your superclass? Is it a framework-provided class, or a custom class from your code? If it's the latter, did you check it for `[super dealloc]` as well? Also, make sure you're not running with the `NSZombieEnabled` environment variable set to `YES`, as that also turns on zombies.

Comment: it is UIView subclass. And yes, NSZombieEnabled is not set to "YES". Right now I am checking out all my code... maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Did you (assuming you're not using ARC) call [super dealloc] at the end of your dealloc method?